# Using oracle easy connect does it really connect to the remote DB?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I tried connecting to remote host db using :

```
 sqlplus abc/abc@hostname1:1000/ABC
```

And tried printing

```
!hostname
```

it still shows me local hostname from which I am running and not HOSTNAME1.

So if I want statistics or run a script on that remote host .. Would it not do that..
i.e. Do I actually get data from remote host?

Is it bcoz !hostname is not a linux command and not a DB command?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple. The `!` prefix in `sqlplus` executes the following text as a command in the local shell.

In your case it's executing the Unix `hostname` command locally.

Query `v$instance` to check the name of the machine you're connected to.

There are ways to execute local Unix commands via the database, but it's seen as a huge security hole, so I won't document them here.

ssh (assuming Unix) into the database host instead.

Comment: Is there a way to run this command on the remote host through sqlplus?